# If command not working with extra conditions

Tags: php

Hi everyone im back with a new problem I have no idea why this is not working...

Ok this is my IF command

```
if(file_exists(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) &&
filesize(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) > 100 &&
time()-filemtime(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) < 168 * 3600 ===FALSE)
```

What I am trying to do is....A) check if the file exists and is over 100bytes and not older then a week...

I really need a inline solution as I have to do a find and replace in notepad as I have this in a few places in my script

Any help would be great

Ok here is the full code ignore the ##url## and ##key## with my last group attempt

```
$hash = hash("sha1","##key##");

if(file_exists(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) && (filesize(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) > 100) && (time()-filemtime(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) < 168 * 3600)){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "###URL###");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    $credits = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $f = fopen(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash,"wb");
    fwrite($f,$credits);
    fclose($f);
        echo "
<script>

   alert(\"Updated Record\");

</script>";
    }else {
        $credits = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash);   
    }

$creditsun= json_decode($credits, true); // Decode the results into an array
```

Comment: So if any of the 3 conditions are flagged it updates the json file

Comment: Why the `===FALSE`???

Comment: When I remove the ===FALSE it always flags :S

Comment: Probably need to group it, not sure: `(time()-filemtime(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash)) < (168 * 3600))`

Comment: Error reporting? - I almost sound like the guy who gave an answer down there.

Comment: Make sure that all of those satisfy the conditions. If one fails, the entire house of cards falls.

Comment: Im not getting any errors :S but nothing im trying is working tried grouping in all different ways aswell

Comment: Ok I updated my post hope that helps?

Comment: I know the file is there and it is over 100 bytes and its only a few hours old

Comment: if I change the file_exists(__DIR__."/uploads/jslon_".$hash) to something to break it like file_exists(__DIR__."/uploads/jsloBADn_".$hash) it doesnt flag the condition. I hope im making sence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove === FALSE at the end?

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) && 
       filesize(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) > 100 && 
       time()-filemtime(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) < 168 * 3600) {
// do stuff here
}
```

**EDIT:**

the negation is obtained by placing ! on the front of the entire condition :

```
if (!(file_exists(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) && 
       filesize(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) > 100 && 
       time()-filemtime(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) < 168 * 3600)) {
// do stuff here
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Have a look at this php manual page [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: I think I need the FALSE because the way around I got my command?

Comment: so if file doesnt exsit and is not over 100bytes and is not newer then a week run this code....

Comment: Then do if (!(file_exists(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) && 
       filesize(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) > 100 && 
       time()-filemtime(__DIR__."/uploads/json_".$hash) < 168 * 3600)) {
// do stuff here
}

Comment: Pretty sure this has fixed it :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped, don't forget to tell this is the right answere ;-)